# Azure B2C Force Password Reset After X Number of Days

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Using the following Docs I've setup an Azure B2C to force password reset after 1 Day.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/force-password-reset?pivots=b2c-user-flow#password-expiry-duration

However, it doesn't seem to be working. Is there more that needs to happen here?

I do notice when looking at a User their "Password Policies" is still "Disable Password Expiration"

Do I need to programmatically remove that for each user? Note we can't use a B2C Custom Policy.

[image]

[image]